# Can one add further source files to an executable once defined?

Tags: cmake

Given I have defined an executable with its main source file in a `CMakeList.txt` file:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(MyExampleApp main.cpp)
```

Can I add further source files to this executable after this line but in the same or an included `CMakeList.txt` file?

Comment: Normally you do that using variables instead of files on your ADD_EXECUTABLE() line.

Comment: @drescherjm gave correct answer - just gather your sources with `list(APPEND SOURCES src.cpp src2.cpp)` or `set(SOURCES src.cpp)` and `set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} src2.cpp)`.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing it like that but it seemed somehow bruteforce. Anyway. It's working.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use `target_sources`, available since cmake 3.1

eg.
`target_sources(MyExampleApp PRIVATE ${extra_file})`

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_sources.html

Comment: If the target is a library (not executable) this trick also works, but you should use `PRIVATE` instead of `PUBLIC`, otherwise the particular source file will get linked twice.

Comment: @MarkLakata I've updated the answer to change it from `PUBLIC` to `PRIVATE`.

Answer (score 9):

I think you may use:

```
add_executable(MyExampleApp main.cpp)
add_library(library STATIC ${ADDITIONAL_SOURCES})
set_target_properties(library PROPERTIES
     LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(MyExampleApp library)
```

Comment: It should be noted that this does not work for Windows resource (.rc) files out-of-the-box even though they can normally be provided as source files to `add_library()`. CMake complains that the "CMAKE_RC_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY" variable is not set. The workaround is to also include an empty .c source file.

Answer (score 4):

It should be noted that for more recent versions of CMake (> 3.1 I think) one can append files to the `SOURCES` property on targets.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/SOURCES.html

Comment: Or you could just use [`target_sources()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_sources.html?highlight=target_sources) (see DarthB's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31541070/4763489)).