# Cmake - how to inject source file into subdirectory project

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake project leveraging another cmake library project, the dir looks like this:

```
/CMakeList.txt 
/main.c
/.gitmodules
/patch/patch.c
/vendor/CMakeList.txt  
/vendor/vendor.c
/vendor/...
```

In `/CMakeList.txt`, I used `add_subdirectory(vendor)` to include/link vendor library to my own project.

In `/vendor/CMakeList.txt`, source file is added by `FILE(GLOB SRC_VEN vendor.c ...)`

I want to inject `/patch/patch.c` into `vendor` library without touching `/vendor` directory, which is a git submodule

Is it possible to use cmake to achieve this in my root CMakeList.txt?

Thanks!

Comment: how does `/vendor/CMakeList.txt` really look like? Doesn't it use a wildcard in `FILE(GLOB ...)`? What do you mean "without touching"? Could any files be changed automatically?

Comment: Something like `target_sources(vendor_target PRIVATE "patch/patch.c")` after your `add_subdirectory(vendor)` call? But you need to know the target's name you want to inject into (`vendor_target` is just a placeholder). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538466/keeping-file-hierarchy-across-subdirectories-in-cmake) for more details.

Comment: Hi @m.s.  thanks for the reply, yes `/vendor/CMakeLists.txt` uses wildcard, i mentioned 'without touch' vendor because I can modify `/vendor/CMakeLists.txt` a little bit, and `ignore=dirty` in my `.gitmodules` so that the change will not be committed

Comment: Thank you, @Florian ! just tested, target_sources works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

If you want to inject sources into an existing target you can use [target_sources()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_sources.html) (introduced with CMake version 3.1).

In your case this would look something like:

**/CMakeLists.txt**

```
...
add_subdirectory(vendor)
target_sources(vendor_target PRIVATE "patch/patch.c")
```

I put `vendor_target` as a placeholder. Please replace it with the real name for the target you want to inject the sources into.

For more details see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538466/keeping-file-hierarchy-across-subdirectories-in-cmake).