# CMake: configure deep sub-folder tree

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

I  still  don't completely understand what is the correct way to configure a CMake project with deep hierarchy of nested folders with the source code.Here,configuring for MSVC 2013

Here is example of such a project:

```
+RootFolder(no code)
    +NestedFolder1(no code)
        +NestedNestedFolder1(has code .h and .cpp)
        +NestedNestedFolder2(has code and nested folder with code)
             +NestedNestedNestedFolder1(has code .h and .cpp)
```

That's how I configure it in CMake:

**RootFolder CMakeLists:**

```
project(MyDemoCmakeProject)
add_subdirectory(NestedFolder1)
```

NestedFolder1 CMakeLists:

```
 add_subdirectory(NestedNestedFolder1)
 add_subdirectory(NestedNestedFolder2)     
 add_definitions(.....)
 include_directories(.....)
```

**NestedNestedFolder1 CMakeLists:**

```
 set(mysources ${sources})
 add_library(MyLib STATIC ${mysources })
```

**NestedNestedFolder2 CMakeLists:**

```
 subdirs(NestedNestedNestedFolder1)
 set(mysources ${sources})
 add_library(MyLib STATIC ${mysources })
```

**NestedNestedNestedFolder1 CMakeLists:**

```
 set(mysources ${sources})
 add_library(MyLib STATIC ${mysources })
```

With this config when running CMake I am getting :

> add_library cannot create target "MyLib" because another target with
>   the same name already exists.The existing target is a  static library
>   created in source directory NestedNestedFolder1

Now,if I remove 
     add_subdirectory(NestedNestedFolder1)
     add_subdirectory(NestedNestedFolder2)

from NestedFolder1 CMakeLists.txt it works ok.I don't completely understand this moment.For example inside NestedNestedFolder2  I also do add_subdirectory for the nested sub-directory but it doesn't complain.Also I don't understand how CMake is able to 'reveal' the subdirs of NestedFolder1  if I don't add_subdirectory() those.From the different examples I understood that each directory that has a subdirectory with the sources must expose it with [subdirs()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/subdirs.html) or [add_subdirectory()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html).What do I miss here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`subdirs` is the old way of adding subdirectories and it has been deprecated. The [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/subdirs.html) say to use `add_subdirectory` instead. The behaviour of `subdirs` is a bit different to `add_subdirectory` because the former also searches for `CMakeLists.txt` files in the subdirectories and adds them automatically.

There are a few approaches for managing deep hierarchies like the scenario you describe. In my personal order of preference:

**APPROACH 1:**

This requires CMake 3.1 or later, since it uses the `target_sources` command. You can define your executable target at the top level and then call `target_sources` in each subdirectory to add sources to it. You can also use `target_include_directories` and `target_compile_definitions` within each subdirectory as necessary instead of calling `add_definitions` and `include_directories` at the top level to make these dependencies attached to the target instead of applying to everything (only really matters here if you added more things to your top level CMakeLists.txt file(s) later). For your scenario, it would look something like the following (I've inserted dummy source file names and compile definitions for illustration purposes):

*RootFolder CMakeLists:*

```
project(MyDemoCmakeProject)

# add_library() requires a source file argument to be
# present, but it can be an empty string if there are
# no source files, headers, etc. that should be added
# from this directory.
add_library(MyLib STATIC "")
add_subdirectory(NestedFolder1)
```

*NestedFolder1 CMakeLists:*

```
add_subdirectory(NestedNestedFolder1)
add_subdirectory(NestedNestedFolder2)
```

*NestedNestedFolder1 CMakeLists:*

```
target_sources(MyLib PRIVATE
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNN1a.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNN1b.cpp"
)
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

*NestedNestedFolder2 CMakeLists:*

```
add_subdirectory(NestedNestedNestedFolder1)
target_sources(MyLib PRIVATE
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNN2a.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNN2b.cpp"
)
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
target_compile_definitions(MyLib PUBLIC -DSOME_VAL=42)
```

*NestedNestedNestedFolder1 CMakeLists:*

```
target_sources(MyLib PRIVATE
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNNN1a.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNNN1b.cpp"
)
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

This approach has the advantage that each subdirectory remains self contained. The upper levels don't have to know what the lower levels are doing. Furthermore, information is added to the target at the level where that information is most relevant/known. One disadvantage is that you have to add each source with its full path, but that is a minor inconvenience.

**APPROACH 2:**

Instead of using `target_sources`, use a variable to accumulate the source file names and add the contents of that variable at the top level after including all the subdirectories. We use `include` rather than `add_subdirectory` as well so that our variable is being manipulated always in the same scope. Since the target isn't defined until *after* pulling in the subdirectories, you also cannot use `target_compile_definitions` or `target_include_directories`, so these too have to be handled through variables.

*RootFolder CMakeLists:*

```
project(MyDemoCmakeProject)

set(MyLib_SOURCES)
set(MyLib_INCLUDE_DIRS)
set(MyLib_DEFINITIONS)
include(NestedFolder1/CMakeLists.txt)
add_library(MyLib STATIC ${MyLib_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC ${MyLib_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_definitions(MyLib PUBLIC ${MyLib_DEFINITIONS})
```

*NestedFolder1 CMakeLists:*

```
include(NestedNestedFolder1/CMakeLists.txt)
include(NestedNestedFolder2/CMakeLists.txt)
```

*NestedNestedFolder1 CMakeLists:*

```
list(APPEND MyLib_SOURCES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNN1a.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNN1b.cpp"
)
list(APPEND MyLib_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

*NestedNestedFolder2 CMakeLists:*

```
include(NestedNestedNestedFolder1/CMakeLists.txt)
list(APPEND MyLib_SOURCES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNN2a.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNN2b.cpp"
)
list(APPEND MyLib_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
list(APPEND MyLib_DEFINITIONS -DSOME_VAL=42)
```

*NestedNestedNestedFolder1 CMakeLists:*

```
list(APPEND MyLib_SOURCES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNNN1a.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileNNN1b.cpp"
)
list(APPEND MyLib_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

The main reason this is inferior to approach 1 is that carrying all the sources, header paths and compile definitions through in variables makes it more fragile. All subdirectories have to play nice and not use the same variable names for anything else (minor problem) and handling paths with embedded spaces requires more care (trickier problem). Another disadvantage is that variable scoping has to be handled more carefully. Any `add_subdirectory` call would change the scope. An advantage of this approach over approach 1 is that it works for much older versions of CMake.

**APPROACH 3:**

Another alternative is to define a library at each subdirectory level and make the top level library link against them. These subdirectory-level libraries could be static or shared libraries, or object libraries (this requires a more recent CMake version). This approach has the advantage that it would work even for old versions of CMake. Disadvantages depend on your point of view. It would lead to a much higher number of targets being defined and it may reduce the effectiveness of parallel builds. For a small number of subdirectories, I'd suggest this approach might actually be the best, but once you grow beyond a couple of subdirectories, things can quickly start getting out of hand.

Comment: Nice stuff.But what about approach 4,like @David Marquant proposed above?That's no need in nested CMakeLists.txt.All the paths to the nested sources are defined at the root CMakeLists.txt file.Is it possible?Is it a good practice?

Comment: Yes, I realised after I posted that I neglected to include that fourth approach. Including all the sources at the top level is simple, but if you're going to do that, then it reduces the value in having subdirectories in the first place. You end up with the top level having to define all your sources and it repeats the subdirectory structure right down to the deepest level. Certainly there are cases where this is okay, but the more files and subdirectories you have, the messier this approach becomes.

Comment: Approach 1 seems cleanest to me.

Comment: @CraigScott could you just extend a little on PRIVATE vs PUBLIC param in target_sources?

Comment: Check out the [docs for target_sources](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) for the details. In short, PRIVATE makes the source get compiled only by the named target while PUBLIC also makes it get compiled by anything that links to it. This may seem odd, but there may be some uses for adding sources that aren't really sources (e.g. headers, images, scripts, etc.) since they should then show up under those targets in IDEs like Visual Studio, Qt Creator, etc. (but I haven't checked/confirmed this).

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538466/keeping-file-hierarchy-across-subdirectories-in-cmake) for similar material.

Comment: A more detailed treatment of the `target_sources()` command used in Approach 1 and its advantages can be found [here](http://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have multiple targets with the same name: "MyLib". Just give each library a unique name and it should work.

Comment: those are not different libraries.I am trying to build a single library from all those subfolders

Comment: I thought that's the way to add the sources to a lib from nested folders  :/

Comment: If the nested folders contain only source there is no need to add a CMakeLists.txt to them. Just add the source files in the NestedFolder dir:

    set(sources NestedNestedFolder1/file1.cpp ... NestedNestedNestedFolder1/filen.cpp)