# In CMake, how can I declare a target and define it later?

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to first declare an target, say, an static library, then feeding its source files according to some options. Is it possible to achieve that?

Say, what I want is a command `target_specify_sources()`, and the full script is like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(hello)
option(USE_PLUGIN "use plugin?" ON)

add_library(my_target STATIC)

if (USE_PLUGIN)
    target_specify_sources(my_target 
        src/base.cpp
        src/plugin.cpp
    )
else()
    target_specify_sources(my_target 
        src/base.cpp
    )
endif()
```

---

update:

I shoud make clear that "to declare a target, means not specifying any source files". The comment mentioned another question link:

[Can one add further source files to an executable once defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339851/can-one-add-further-source-files-to-an-executable-once-defined)

there is `target_sources()` command since cmake 3.1, but it is not "declare target".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339851/can-one-add-further-source-files-to-an-executable-once-defined ?

Comment: In your example you could just add `src/base.cpp` to your add_library() and add the additional source for the plugin optionally using `target_sources()`

Comment: @KamilCuk Oh thanks for mentions that question. I never know `target_sources()` until you and drescherjm mentioned.

Comment: @drescherjm But I still have to specify at least one source file when defining my target. I just feel that this is not really "modern cmake" that "target oriented".